# Split content in last parantheses

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, how  can I split string to get content of last parantheses so

```
var str = "Lorem ipsum (I don't want this data) lorem ipsum (I want this data)";
```

becames array

```
["Lorem ipsum (I don't want this data) lorem ipsum "],["I want this data"]
```

Comment: And what have you been trying to get that result so far?

Comment: str.substr('(') + some "calculations" and so on

Comment: As someone who isn't great as regular expressions: I would split the string by `(`, get the last array item and split that string by `)` and get the first item.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 You can do all in one regular expression with two capturing groups. See my answer.

Comment: @dystroy I know. Just providing a more understandable yet slightly less efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) :

```
var arr = str.match(/^(.*)\(([^\)]+)\)$/).slice(1);
```

This produces exactly

```
["Lorem ipsum (I don't want this data) lorem ipsum ", "I want this data"]
```

[Online explanation of the regex](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%28.%2a%29%5C%28%28%5B%5E%5C%29%5D%2b%29%5C%29%24)

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer approaches without regex, mainly for performance. It may not be pretty, but it works nontheless!

```
var str = "Lorem ipsum (I don't want this data) lorem ipsum (I want this data)";

var s = str.lastIndexOf('(');
var e = str.lastIndexOf(')');
var l = e - s;

var data = [
    str.substr(0, s).trim(),
    str.substr(s + 1, l - 1).trim()
];

// data = ["Lorem ipsum (I don't want this data) lorem ipsum", "I want this data"]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I like it because it looks more clear than regex (to regex noob). Upvoted :)